# Spurious factor of 2 in Salakhutdinov's MatLab RBM code

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

I'm trying to pick apart http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/DBM.html

Specifically http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/code_DBM/rbm.m

That file troubles me, because there is a `2*` factor appearing for no good reason that I can see. It seems to be doubling up the pre-activation energy for the hidden layer.

I've pulled up https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/guideTR.pdf alongside and there is no mention of such a factor.

The only possible `2*` I can think of might come from calculating the overall energy of a particular vis-hid configuration: $-E(v,h) = \sum a_i v_i + \sum b_j h_j + \sum_{i<j} v_i h_j w_{ij} $ where you require $i<j$ to avoid counting each weight twice. But clearly that's not what's going on here.

So my question is: what is the purpose of this factor of 2?

---

PS No tag for RBM!

PPS The code is really tricky to follow, I've rewritten it here (how to fix wonky syntax highlighting?):

```
function rbm(maxepoch, numhid, batchdata, restart)
    binarySampleFrom = @(T) T > rand(size(T)); % T is a tensor
    activationFunc = @(E) 1 ./ (1 + exp(-E));

    if restart == 1,
        %restart=0;

        eps_w      = 0.05;   % Learning rate for weights 
        eps_vb     = 0.05;   % Learning rate for biases of visible units 
        eps_hb     = 0.05;   % Learning rate for biases of hidden units 

        %CD=1;   
        weightCost = 0.001;   
        momInitial = 0.5;
        momFinal   = 0.9;

        [itemsPerBatch, nPixels, nBatches] = size(batchdata);
        N = itemsPerBatch;
        epoch=1;

        % Initializing symmetric weights and biases. 
        vishid     = 0.001*randn(nPixels, numhid);
        hidbiases  = zeros(1,numhid);
        visbiases  = zeros(1,nPixels);

        vishidinc  = zeros(nPixels,numhid);
        hidbiasinc = zeros(1,numhid);
        visbiasinc = zeros(1,nPixels);
    end    

tic
    for epoch = epoch:maxepoch
        fprintf(1,'epoch %d\r',epoch);
        errsum=0;
        for batch = 1:nBatches,
            if mod(batch,10) == 9,
                fprintf(1,'.');
            end

            data = batchdata(:,:,batch);

            [avSynapseExcitation, visBias, hidBias, av_err] = getState( data );

            % keep a tally of average divergence of reconstructions from
            % original sampled vis-vector.
            errsum = av_err + errsum;

            % Update weights & biases
            momentum = (epoch<=5)*momInitial + (epoch>5)*momFinal;

            vishidinc  = momentum*vishidinc  + eps_w * ( avSynapseExcitation - weightCost*vishid);
            visbiasinc = momentum*visbiasinc + eps_vb * visBias;
            hidbiasinc = momentum*hidbiasinc + eps_hb * hidBias;

            vishid    = vishid    + vishidinc;
            visbiases = visbiases + visbiasinc;
            hidbiases = hidbiases + hidbiasinc;
        end
        fprintf(1, ' error %4.2f  \n', errsum / nBatches);

    end
toc

    save data/out/1_fullmnistvh.mat  vishid visbiases hidbiases epoch

    function [avSynapseExcitation, visBias, hidBias, av_err] = getState( data )
        visbias = repmat(   visbiases, N, 1 );
        hidbias = repmat( 2*hidbiases, N, 1 );

        % - - - - -  POSITIVE PHASE  - - - - - 

        % Consider data (28*28 greyscale pixels ranging 0.0 to 1.0) as probabilities
        visPD = data;

        % convert each pixel to 0 or 1 accordingly to get VIS outputs.
        sampleFromVis = binarySampleFrom( visPD );

        % Clamping VIS, get HID layer activations, i.e. POSTERIOR dist. for HID
        % 100x784 * 784*10 = 100*10
        hidPD = activationFunc( sampleFromVis*(2*vishid) + hidbias ); % Eq. 7

        % 784 vis/inputs going to 10 hiddens = a 784x10 v_i h_j matrix.
        % Sum over all batch items:  784x100 * 100x10 -> 784x10
        avSynapseStrength_clampingV = sampleFromVis' * hidPD  / N;

        % Get expected activations for each visible and hidden neuron
        avVisAct   = mean( sampleFromVis ); % <v_i h_j>_data in Eq. 5
        avHidAct   = mean( hidPD );


        % - - - - -  NEGATIVE PHASE  - - - - - 

        % Sample from our posterior dist. for HID
        sampleFromHid = binarySampleFrom( hidPD );            

        % Clamping HID to this sample, get a POSTERIOR dist. for VIS ...
        visReconPD = activationFunc( sampleFromHid*vishid' + visbias ); % Eq. 8

        % ... from which we sample a 'Reconstruction' vis/data-vector ...
        visRecon = binarySampleFrom( visReconPD );

        % ... and throw it back thru hidden units to get a 'neg' HID dist.
        newHidPD = activationFunc( visRecon*(2*vishid) + hidbias );

        avSynapseStrength_threshold  = visRecon' * newHidPD  / N;

        avVisAct_neg = mean( visRecon ); % <-- why not use visReconPD & sampleFromVis?
        avHidAct_neg = mean( newHidPD );

        %  - - - - -  Display  - - - - - 
        if rem( batch, 600 ) == 0
            figure(1);
            dispims( visRecon', 28, 28 );
            drawnow;
        end

        pix_diffs = visRecon - sampleFromVis;
        sq_errs = sum(pix_diffs .^ 2, 2);
        av_err = sqrt( mean(sq_errs) );

        avSynapseExcitation = avSynapseStrength_clampingV - avSynapseStrength_threshold;
        visBias = avVisAct - avVisAct_neg;
        hidBias = avHidAct - avHidAct_neg;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given in [Hinton & Salakhutdinov 2006 -- Deep Boltzmann Machines](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/dbm.pdf), Section 3.1: Greedy Layerwise Pretraining of DBMs.

It looks as though this code could possibly be considered an accompaniment to this paper.

I won't attempt to paraphrase Hinton -- the paper is in the public domain.